# I installed yarn globally in my ubuntu20 vps, but when I use yarn, it says Command 'yarn' not found,

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I use those cmd to install yarn:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
npm install -g yarn
```

but when I use yarn -v, it shows Command 'yarn' not found. So what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

https://techcolleague.com/yarn-command-not-found/

you will need to add the install path to your .bashrc/.zshrc and reload your terminal/ssh session (or restart your machine)

supplemental info:
in my bash scripts that which I use to deploy apps, I hard code the yarn path and most other executables because of weird nuances

```sh
YARN=/usr/bin/yarn
PM2=/usr/bin/pm2
$YARN run productionStart
$PM2 save
```

you will know where your yarn instance is installed by doing `which yarn`

Comment: thanks, but it didn't solved my problem, I decide to change another VPS, I think that will works